Old Sci-Fi space movie with humans and aliens working together in same ship
A long time back, I saw a sci-fi space movie with humans and aliens working together on the same ships. I remember a dialogue where an alien says human spaceships are not beautiful and look like engines bolted onto cargo containers. Then the human (lead character) says it doesn't matter how it looks in the vacuum of space.
I don't even remember the movie's premise or if it was any good, but this dialogue stuck with me and I think about it when I see new sci-fi spaceship designs. Does anyone know the movie?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be more specific about when you saw this?  (i.e. What year?)  Where did you see it?  (Country, TV, theatre, online...)

How that alien looked like
?

was it a live action or animated film?

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

Was it hybrid (animated/live) like in "Star Trek Wars"?

It was a live-action film; I saw it too long ago to remember when. I didn't even have any other impression of the movie than I mentioned. As @Shawn mentioned, it is Babylon 5 - The Legend of the Rangers.

The Babylon 5 made-for-tv movie The Legend of the Rangers has this quote, spoken by an alien Minbari character, about the experimental ship Valen:

If human military designers had their way every colour of the spectrum would be removed except for grey, green and black and we would all live in windowless boxes.


Trying to find a clip of the scene to see if the rest of the question matches

Good find.  To the person asking the question- this was a bad and lazy film that makes one feel sorry for actors that had every reason to think they were signing on to something well written like the rest of the Babylon 5/Crusade franchise with very few exceptions.

Funny, I read the question and thought "I wonder if this is Babylon 5?". It just has that kind of feel to it.

Can't find a clip and all the legal options for me to watch the entire thing involve spending money I don't want to (because as much as I love B5 this was a terrible installment aside from some scenes with G'Kar) so I can't flesh out the answer more for now.

@N.Virgo - It would make sense. In the universe of B5, Humans were very new to interstellar travel, and had spent a lot of that time since fighting desperately for survival. They hadn't really had a lot of time and energies to spare to work on the aesthetics of their warships. They also were new enough to not have artificial gravity on their ships, relying on rotating sections for a gravity-like internal environment, which rather restricts the design choices available for long-haul spacecraft.

@Shawn I had a quick look at the movie, and it is the one you mentioned. I didn't even remember that it was a Babylon 5 movie. It was long ago and didn't leave much of an impression other than that dialogue. It is kind of a trope in SciFi now.

@lucasbachmann Had a fast run-through of the movie. Yes, it is a movie that was probably funded only for the Babylon 5 association. It could have been better. I saw it a long time back, and the only impression it left in my memory was of that dialogue. I didn't even remember that it was a Babylon 5 movie. On rewatch, I did recollect that goofy AR weapons control pod.
